# Scale div according to screen width with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I make a function in JavaScript make div or img or a padding Scale depending on screen width?

I don't want to use the CSS solution

This is for a div padding am using

```
@media(min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 399px) {div.hero-position {padding-top: 58px; padding-bottom: 36px;}}
@media (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 499px) {div.hero-position {padding-top: 71px; padding-bottom: 48px;}}
@media (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 599px) {div.hero-position {padding-top: 82px; padding-bottom: 60px;}}
@media (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 699px) {div.hero-position {padding-top: 98px; padding-bottom: 72px;}}
@media (min-width: 700px) and (max-width: 799px) {div.hero-position {padding-top: 99px; padding-bottom: 84px}}
@media (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 899px) {div.hero-position {padding-top: 116px; padding-bottom: 96px;}}
@media (min-width: 900px) and (max-width: 999px) {div.hero-position {padding-top: 124px; padding-bottom: 108px}}
@media (min-width: 1000px) and (max-width: 1099px) {div.hero-position {padding-top: 118px; padding-bottom: 120px;}}
@media (min-width: 1100px) and (max-width: 1199px) {div.hero-position {padding-top: 140px; padding-bottom: 132px;}}
@media (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1299px) {div.hero-position {padding-top: 174px; padding-bottom: 144px;}}
@media (min-width: 1300px) and (max-width: 1399px) {div.hero-position {padding-top: 203px; padding-bottom: 156px;}}
@media (min-width: 1400px) and (max-width: 1499px) {div.hero-position {padding-top: 218px; padding-bottom: 168px;}}
@media (min-width: 1500px) {div.hero-position {padding-top: 239px; padding-bottom: 180px;}}
```

Comment: Do you not want to use the css solution because what you have is cumbersome or is there some other reason? If the support is sufficient for you, you can try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp or just use percentages.

Comment: @jmargolisvt `clamp()` is quite new and not, yet, well supported. It's also probably not really what the OP is wanting, although it could be a portion of what's desired.

Comment: Is your **real** requirement that this be done by JavaScript, or just in a way that's easier than the quite cumbersome CSS you are currently using? Will an easier CSS solution be acceptable? Are the *exact* pixel values for `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` critical, or are you just looking for something that looks good at those viewport widths? Do the effective values for values for `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` *have to* jump from defined pixel value to pixel value, or is continuous variation acceptable?

Comment: @Mayken "well-supported" is a matter of opinion here. I am using it in production on thousands of sites that collectively get millions of hits every day.  It really depends on what the OP's browser support reqs are.

Comment: As is almost always the case, yes, "well supported" depends on your definitions. I admit that I was basing my statement on the [Browser Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp#Browser_compatibility) information on MDN, which indicates that it's not yet supported on some mobile platforms. But, to be frank, my comment was mostly because what `clamp()` does really isn't what the code the OP shows indicates they are doing (i.e. it doesn't appear to be the main thing the OP is interested in), although it *might be* useful, depending on what the OP *really* wants.

Comment: By the way, why are `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` varying so substantially based on the viewport *width*? Wouldn't that be something you'd want to change based on the *height*?

Answer (score 2):

What about a better CSS solution? The [`vw` unit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#vw) would let you set padding as a percentage of viewport (screen) width:

```
div.hero-position {
  padding-top: 3vw; /* 3% of width */
  padding-bottom: 2vw; /* 2% of width */
}
```